# PHP Error con array

Tags: php

A qué se debe este error de php Notice: Undefined offset: 58

Salta ese error al usar la siguiente función, más especificamente en la línea marcada con el comentario.

```
<?php

    public function repeatLine($string){
        $array = str_split($string);
        for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
            if($array[$i] == "-" && $array[$i+1] == "-"){ ///////Acá salta el error!
                $array[$i+1] = "";
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. tal vez el error está porque en `$array[$i+1]` es mas allá de la cantidad de datos del arreglo, pero, sin una descripción clara de cómo y para qué está usando este código, es difícil darle una respuesta acertada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque en la última iteración del ciclo, estás intentando acceder a un índice inexistente en el arreglo.

Eso se da en la línea que marcas porque allí estás colocando `$i+1`, y eso, en la práctica significa que si la posición de la iteración es 0, tú accedes a la posición 1, y así, hasta el final. Pero precisamente al final, cuando ya has llegado a la última iteración del ciclo, cuando `$i` equivale al `count()-1`, tú quieres acceder a la posición igual a `count()`, la que en PHP no puede ser accedida: recuerda que los arreglos en PHP parten en base 0, por lo que si el arreglo tiene 7 elementos, el último índice será 6. Luego, cuando tú intentas ingresar a la posición 7, te salta ese error.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.

Comment: @Camilo, recuerda marcar esta respuesta como [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: En unos minutos cuando me deje, pero una pregunta, de qué manera podría validar para que reconozca que no existe ese índice?

Comment: Itera el bucle con la condicion ( $i<count($array) - 1). con eso resuelves parte de tu problema. En general, si el array tiene N elementos, recorre siempre desde 0 hasta N-1.

Comment: Para lo que lo estoy usando no me funciona, pero ya lo solucioné, gracias.